# How to run app on moto 360 from android studio

Tags: android

I'm using the sample watchface app and have followed all the steps 
(developer.android + several variations from this site) to run something on my watch but with no joy. Wondering if anyone can advise please.

Phone (moto 4G) is connected to PC by USB. USB debugging is on in Settings and Debugging over Bluetooth is on in Android Wear app. Paired watch (moto 360 2gen) has ADB Debugging enabled and Debugging over Bluetooth enabled.

Android Studio lists the phone if I run the phone module part of the app; it offers no compatible devices if I run the wearable module. Adb devices command just lists the phone. On the phone in the Android Wear app under Debugging over Bluetooth it says
Host: disconnected
Target: connected.

When I look on the phone in Settings, Apps a watchFace app has appeared but there's nothing on the watch (tried to change watch face, nothing new; no new app).

I tried

```
 adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
 adb connect localhost 4444
```

but the second command gives
'unable to connect to localhost:4444 ... no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (10061).'
I also tried

```
 adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444
```

which does connect but AS says it's offline.

Can anyone help?

Comment: After same problem several times (adb connecting but offline), today it worked. Double-checked spelling/syntax same as previous times, don't yet know why it works now. Hope it continues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying the above procedure many times it seems that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't! I haven't yet found what makes the difference but suspect either (a) not leaving enough time between connecting phone and entering adb commands or (b) simple PC running too slowly.